# PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'JANUARY_2020' not allowed in this context

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using this code to see if it will work for a procedure. I want to be able to make a procedure in which i can decide what data to extract by typing the time ('jan-2020') in which it is recorded and also to decide in which table i want to place the data in (january_2020). i get the error that the table is not able to be used in this context. What do i have to change in the code to be in the right context?

Is it because i am using dynamic sql in a loop that requires the loop to be executed to put the data in the table? or is it because i am using %rowtype as the attribute for the table ALL_DATA to create its own columns? If it is any of these what should i do to change it?

```
DECLARE
time_v varchar2(9);
table_v varchar2(200);
sql_code varchar2(300);

TYPE Copied_Table IS TABLE OF Gastos%ROWTYPE;

All_Data    Copied_Table;

BEGIN

time_v := 'jan-2020';

SELECT *
BULK COLLECT INTO All_Data FROM Gastos
Where TO_CHAR(DATE_, 'MON-YYYY') = UPPER(time_v);


FOR I in All_Data.First .. All_Data.Last LOOP

sql_code := 'INSERT INTO :table_v ( DATE_, DESCRIPTION, ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT,             
TRANSACTION_TYPE, CATEGORY, ACCOUNT_NAME)
Values ( ALL_Data(i).date_, ALL_Data(i).description, ALL_Data(i).original_description,                             
ALL_Data(i).amount, ALL_Data(i).transaction_type, ALL_Data(i).category, ALL_Data(i).account_name)';

table_v := january_2020;

execute immediate sql_code 
using table_v;

END LOOP;

END upload_monthly_expenses;
```

Comment: `january_2020` is not a `varchar2` literal, `'january_2020'` is. Change `table_v := january_2020;` to `table_v := 'january_2020';`.

Comment: What you're trying to do seems questionable though, Why not just using a query with a `WHERE` clause filtering the time?

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `TO_CHAR(DATE_, 'MON-YYYY') = UPPER(time_v)`, i.e. applying a function to a column in the `WHERE` clause as this makes indexes useless (unless you have an FBI on with the expression). Use a range like `_date >= to_date('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND _date < to_date('2020-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Comment: And you don't need the loop. That's just killing performance. An `INSERT ... SELECT ...` or even a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...` would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

Pass table name as input parameter and  replace bind variable with normal variable for the table name and concatenate it to the DML statement.Modify your code as below,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upload_monthly_expenses(table_v IN VARCHAR2,time_v IN VARCHAR2) AS
    DECLARE
    sql_code varchar2(300);

    TYPE Copied_Table IS TABLE OF Gastos%ROWTYPE;

    All_Data    Copied_Table;

    BEGIN


    SELECT *
    BULK COLLECT INTO All_Data FROM Gastos
    Where TO_CHAR(DATE_, 'MON-YYYY') = UPPER(time_v);


    FOR I in All_Data.First .. All_Data.Last LOOP        

    sql_code := 'INSERT INTO '||table_v||' ( DATE_, DESCRIPTION, ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT,             
    TRANSACTION_TYPE, CATEGORY, ACCOUNT_NAME)
    Values ( ALL_Data(i).date_, ALL_Data(i).description, ALL_Data(i).original_description,                             
    ALL_Data(i).amount, ALL_Data(i).transaction_type, ALL_Data(i).category, ALL_Data(i).account_name)';

    execute immediate sql_code;

    END LOOP;

    END;
```

From a PL/SQL block procedure can be executed as below,

```
BEGIN
upload_monthly_expenses('jan-2020','january_2020');
END;
```